# Pandas read xml in an excel column , and create new columns based on data

Tags: xml, pandas

I have a excel, which has data column with data in xml format.

```
ID  Color   Payload                                                                              Misc
1   Green   <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>001</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 1</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   23
2   Yellow  <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>002</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 2</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   34
3   Blue    <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>003</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 3</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   3UE
4   Red     <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>004</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 4</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   534
5   Orange  <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>005</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 5</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   RUE
```

How do I read the payload in pandas, and spit out each element as column, i.e. something like below:

```
ID  Color   Payload                                                                              MainNode SubNode ID  Name    Misc
1   Green   <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>001</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 1</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   Insert   EMP    001 Name 1  23
2   Yellow  <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>002</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 2</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   Insert   EMP    002 Name 2  34
3   Blue    <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>003</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 3</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   Insert   EMP    003 Name 3  3UE
4   Red     <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>004</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 4</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   Insert   EMP    004 Name 4  534
5   Orange  <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>005</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 5</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   Insert   EMP    005 Name 5  RUE
```

Comment: maybe you want to extract those values like from string? with `str.extract()` ? eg `df['Name'] =df['Payload'].str.extract('ebo:([A-Za-z)')`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use find() and a loop (with index) to do it:

```
df['MainNode'] = df['Payload']
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    df['MainNode'][i] = df['MainNode'][i][df['MainNode'][i].find('<')+1 : df['MainNode'][i].find('>')]

df['ID'] = df['Payload']
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    df['ID'][i] = df['ID'][i][df['ID'][i].find('<ebo:Id>')+8 : df['ID'][i].find('</ebo:Id>')]

df['Name'] = df['Payload']
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    df['Name'][i] = df['Name'][i][df['Name'][i].find('<ebo:Name>')+10 : df['Name'][i].find('</ebo:Name>')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take approach of converting xml to JSON so that it's more friendly to `python` and `pandas`.  I've used [xmlplain](https://pypi.org/project/xmlplain/) for this

1. generate a new temporary column that is payload as JSON.  Also reformatted it from `{'Insert': {'emp:Emp': [{'ebo:Id': '001'}, {'ebo:Name': 'Name 1'}]}}` to `{'Main': 'Insert', 'SubNode': 'emp:Emp', 'ebo:Id': '001', 'ebo:Name': 'Name 1'}`
2. make a new dataframe from this column and `concat()` it back so now you have all the columns

```
import xmlplain


data = """ID  Color   Payload                                                                              Misc
1   Green   <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>001</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 1</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   23
2   Yellow  <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>002</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 2</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   34
3   Blue    <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>003</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 3</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   3UE
4   Red     <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>004</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 4</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   534
5   Orange  <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>005</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 5</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   RUE """
a = [[t.strip().replace(",", "") for t in re.split("  ",l) if t!=""]  for l in [l for l in data.split("\n")]]

# massage the json from xmlplain to pandas column format
def nicejson(js):
    return {**{"Main":k for k in js.keys()}, 
     **{"SubNode":k for k in js["Insert"].keys()},
     **{k:v for attset in js["Insert"]["emp:Emp"] for k,v in attset.items() }
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(a[1:], columns=a[0])
df = df.assign(jsonraw=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: nicejson(xmlplain.xml_to_obj(r["Payload"])), axis=1))
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df["jsonraw"].to_dict()).T], axis=1).drop("jsonraw", axis=1)

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
ID   Color                                                                              Payload Misc    Main  SubNode ebo:Id ebo:Name
 1   Green  <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>001</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 1</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   23  Insert  emp:Emp    001   Name 1
 2  Yellow  <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>002</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 2</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>   34  Insert  emp:Emp    002   Name 2
 3    Blue  <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>003</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 3</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>  3UE  Insert  emp:Emp    003   Name 3
 4     Red  <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>004</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 4</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>  534  Insert  emp:Emp    004   Name 4
 5  Orange  <Insert><emp:Emp><ebo:Id>005</ebo:Id><ebo:Name>Name 5</ebo:Name></emp:Emp></Insert>  RUE  Insert  emp:Emp    005   Name 5
```